# NFS Server has low performance

Tags: debian, nfs

First of all, here are the specs of the server we are talking about (only the relevant stuff):

- AMD-6400K with AES-NI
- 6x3TB WD Red HDDs in Software Raid5 (AES encrypted)
- 16GB of DDR3 RAM

The overall performance of the HDDs is about 300 - 400MB/s in sequential write/read. The problem is now that it is severly slower when using NFS. It it connected to my PC with a Gigabit network, which should give me a maximum of 120MB/s. But I only come to 17MB/s per second. I once had this server running with Gentoo Linux, Raid5 and NFS and had about 110MB/s. Now it is running with Debian. Unfortunately, I cannot remember my old NFS settings (via Samba the server reaches about 90MB/s btw). This is my current setup:

```
/nfs/data   bueckstueck01(rw,sync,nohide,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000) 192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0(ro,sync,nohide,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
```

and I mount it via:

```
mount.nfs -o users,exec,rw,wsize=8192,rsize=8192 databueck01:/nfs/data /mnt/data
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong or what you think would be more optimized settings? I am mainly backupping Systems via TAR (single file, sequential write) on this server, so I do not copy multiple small data files on it which would generate a massive overhead. I pipe the systems backup files to tar and direct that directly on the server.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The `sync` (synchronous) setting is probably your bottleneck. You may consider trying to export with the `async` (asynchronous) flag, depending on your workload.

Try benchmarking with it.

Comment: Thank you. I read about that just this moment that this flushes everything directly to physical memory and thus ignoring the cache... I will try this as soon as the current backup sequence is completed. Thanks!

Comment: :/. Does not seem to change anything. At first it looks like it is faster, but later on it gets more hangup times o_O.

Comment: Its fascinating. Either there is something severly broken in arch linux or i am just too dumb to use it. With the same paramters on the same machine on gentoo it is rocket fast...